# Does `chmod +x` make a file an executable or does it assign execute permission on the file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, permissions, chmod

Does `chmod +x` make a file an executable or does it assign execute permission on the file?

For example - `chmod 111` will allow execute permission to user, group, everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

It assigns a permission.

per [chmod(1) - OpenBSD manual pages](https://man.openbsd.org/chmod.1)

> The chmod utility modifies the file mode bits of the listed files as specified by the mode operand. The mode of a file dictates its permissions, among other attributes.

Based on some reading over here: [Mode Structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Mode-Structure.html#:%7E:text=The%20file%20mode%20bits%20have,permission%20to%20read%20the%20file.)
The file mode bits that are being modified are "file permission bits"

> 27.1 Structure of File Mode Bits
> The file mode bits have two parts: the file permission bits, which control ordinary access to the file, and special mode bits, which affect only some files.
> There are three kinds of permissions that a user can have for a file:
>
> 1. permission to read the file. For directories, this means permission to list the contents of the directory.
> 2. permission to write to (change) the file. For directories, this means permission to create and remove files in the directory.
> 3. permission to execute the file (run it as a program). For directories, this means permission to access files in the directory.

This was some neat reading.